# Substituting soy milk for regular (cow) milk in crepes/pancakes

Tags: milk, pancakes, crepe, soymilk

I normally make my Swedish pancakes with soy milk because my SO has a dairy sensitivity. But today I used cow's milk, and I noticed that my pancakes seemed to brown a lot faster than they usually do, resulting in an unattractive dark brown shade.

Is there anything to this, or was I imagining things?

---

(I checked out [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3842/can-i-substitute-soy-milk-when-a-recipe-for-baking-calls-for-regular-milk), which pertains to baking, and [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13323/can-i-substitute-soy-milk-when-a-recipe-for-cooking-not-baking-calls-for-regul), which focuses on pasta and mashed potatoes, but I figure that pancakes/crepes might have a slightly different answer.)

Answer (score 3):

Browning depends a lot on available sugar: if soya was unsweetened and skim milk was now used (higher lactose than 3%), I could see quicker browning.